# Why does Ubuntu 13.10 not detect my Win7 partition?

Tags: filesystem, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 7 on my DELL INSPIRON 14z 5423 laptop and I'm new to all of this.

I'm using the Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit ISO burned onto a CD.

The first time I tried to install it, Ubuntu said it did not detect any other OS, which meant I only had 4 options:

- Erase disk and install Ubuntu (I don't want to do this)
- Encrypt new Ubuntu.
- Use LVM.
- Something else.

If I choose the Something else option, it brings me to the partition menu and says that I have 1 disk with free space of  (500Gb), but that's not true because I have Windows 7.

I restarted the laptop several times and booted the CD again and I got exactly the same as I did previously.

How do fix this problem and install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7?

After executing "sudo fdisk -l" command in terminal

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd2b811c5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   314574847   157184000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       314574848   629147647   157286400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       629147648   976771071   173811712    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

After removing one partition I executed command once again

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd2b811c5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   629145599   314469376    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       629147648   976771071   173811712    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

[image]

I have WIN7 home perimum os it shows local drive as
[image]

Comment: Check out if your windows 7 is 32-bit. Because you just download the 64-bit Ubuntu iso. So the Ubuntu install can't recognize the 32-bit windows 7. Now, you still get 2 choices: download the 32-bit Ubuntu iso and install it again or install the Ubuntu 32-bit in Vmware.

Comment: How many partition does your Windows have. Is it C only or you have two or more partition? Just shrink the partition from windows to get an unallocated space and install ubuntu on that partition. Reply of it works or doesnt.

Comment: While you use Ubuntu live CD, open a terminal and type `sudo fdisk -l`. Edit your question and add the output, please *don't use comments for the new information** (this are comments). Also, you sure you are able to boot to windows?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/366153/ubuntu-installer-is-not-detecting-windows-and-existing-partitions

Comment: @ Aatish Sai i have 3 partitions c,d,e

Comment: @Braiam i have executed and output is written please see

Comment: i removed but it is not installing

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of gparted?

Comment: @Braiam i have attached please go through

Comment: @goutham your fdisk -l output indicates that you have a GPT partition and warns that fdisk doesn't support that. gdisk supports GPT partitions. sudo apt-get gdisk to install and gdisk -l /dev/sda and provide that output please

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Ubuntu 13.10, try the live version, go through the installation steps and install Ubuntu. If you have Windows on your machine, it will recognize your Windows system and save its bootloader. I've done the same way on my desktop and my laptop and it went well. I had Windows 7 on both machines.

Comment: i tried but no use..it just saying that i have 1 disk

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just had the same problem. in my case i had to install it along with windows 7 for some software i need and my pc came with windows 8. so before switching to windows 7 i was able to install ubuntu and all went fine, but then, i decided to delete all and install win 7 and then ubuntu and then when i tried to do that, i had that problem, it turns out that when you do that with windows installer it only deletes one part of the partition table and left another, so ubuntu installer get confused and sees your disk as "empty" even when linux kernel is able to see your partitions. After days of googling i found a solution that work just fine for me. please check this:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/

you need to download it and run it. (first i donwloaded in windows but it didnt run properly so i use my live cd of ubuntu to donwload it and install it and then run it)

Follow the steps and the important thing is this command:

fixparts /dev/sda

note that it says sda, in my case, the first hard disk was a. try it. if thats your problem, you will see that it tells you a message that you have letf over info in your partiition table that is not right and if you want to delete it, press y and then, exit it and run your instalator, it worked well for me

hope it helps

Comment: software name i cannot find it....it is test disk ????