# Ubuntu installer is not detecting Windows and existing partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, wubi, mbr

While installing Ubuntu 12.04/13.04, the installer doesn't detect my partitions and my Windows 7 OS, so I can't install them side by side.

I created partition D through the Windows tool, but I can't see it.

In the Ubuntu home screen while I'm trying Ubuntu in a live session I can see the partitions.

I tried to use WUBI as well, but I got an error message that "image file not found" or something like that.

What should I do to install Ubuntu alongside Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you have one of two problems:

- **Leftover RAID data** -- This can usually be fixed by typing `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` at a Linux shell prompt, changing `/dev/sda` to the device filename, if it's not `/dev/sda`.
- **A damaged partition table** -- Many problems with MBR partition tables can be fixed with my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program; see its documentation for details. You'll probably need to run the Windows version or run it from an emergency disc like [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php), though.